# Using zoom with Swiper JS for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I have a slider which is rendered using map(). I need to apply zoom to an img, SwiperJS documentation for React doesn't say anything about it :(
I used zoom from swiperJS modules, didn't help

```js
const Blog = () => {
  return ( <
    <
    Swiper modules = {
      [Navigation]
    }
    slidesPerView = {
      2
    }
    spaceBetween = {
      40
    }
    navigation > {
      slideObj.map((obj) => ( <
        SwiperSlide key = {
          obj.imageUrl
        } >
        <
        img className = "blog__image "
        src = {
          obj.imageUrl
        }
        alt = "Photo" / >
        <
        div className = "blog__text" > {
          obj.discription
        } < /div> < /
        SwiperSlide >
      ))
    } <
    /Swiper> < /
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

Comment: You said you tried Zoom, but zoom isn't enabled, and you haven't added Zoom as a module. There are examples https://swiperjs.com/demos#zoom, written in React, that you can even paste.

Comment: I did not add to the message the part of the code where I tried. Thank you very much for the link, you helped me a lot